# test devise_token_auth: Could not find devise mapping for path "/api/v1/auth"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, token

I am trying to test create a user. Here is

**registrations_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController, type: :controller do
  before :each do
    post :create, params:{email:"w@123.com",password:"123123",password_confirmation:"123123"}
    @data = JSON.parse(response.body)
  end

  describe "Register a user" do
    it "request should be successful" do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end
  end

end
```

when i run the test i got:

```
Failures:

  1) DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController Register a user request should be successful
     Failure/Error: post :create, params:{email:"w@123.com",password:"123123",password_confirmation:"123123"}

     AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
       Could not find devise mapping for path "/api/v1/auth".
       This may happen for two reasons:

       1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example:

         devise_scope :user do
           get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"
         end

       2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router.
          If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use:

          @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
     # ./spec/controllers/devise_token_auth/registrations_controller_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.01477 seconds (files took 1.76 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/devise_token_auth/registrations_controller_spec.rb:10 # DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController Register a user request should be successful
```

The message provides two ways:
1) I tried to add the first into routes but not works, where or how should i add it.
2) I added `@request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]` in before block but doesn't work.

How should i solve this? thank you!

Here's my **routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace :api do
    scope :v1 do
      mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

check in console: `Devise.mappings`, that will give you a hint.

In my case I had to call

`request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:api_v1_user]`

instead of

`request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]`